# Php value in Url Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, vhosts

I have a bug in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^(.*)/modalbox/.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.wiglost\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wiglost\.com/modalbox/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.wiglost\.com$
RewriteRule ^([\a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.\/]*)\.php$ index\.php?acc=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.wiglost\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.wiglost\.com$
RewriteRule ^show\.html$ index\.php?acc=%1&show [L]
```

The domain `example.wiglost.com` is OK but `example.wiglost.com/show.html` does not correspond to `wiglost.com?acc=example&show` but action with `show` is not carried out but the action with `acc` is OK.

Comment: Could you explain the problem a little more clearly.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wiglost\.com/modalbox/$`, remove the `/modalbox/` from that since it's not going to show up in the "Host" field.

Comment: I want that when example.wiglost.com is typed that redirects on wiglost.com?acc=example and when example.wiglost.com/show.html is typed that redirects on wiglost.com?acc=example&show. But my script does not function because it redirects all the time on wiglost.com?acc=example. :s

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show.html` redirects to `index.php`, but then `index.php` will be matched by the first rule, as `index.php` matches `^([\a-zA-Z0-9-_./]*).php$, and the show parameter will be overwritten.

Try adding `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` before the other rules.